# iOSでRealmに初期データをセットしたい

Tags: ios, swift, realm

現在実装中のアプリでRealmを使用しています。
アプリ初回起動時にRealmにデータをサーバから取得してセットするのですが、データ量が多すぎるため、あらかじめデータをセットした状態でリリースする方法はどうすればよいでしょうか？

Answer (score 3, accepted):

あらかじめ、シミュレータなどを使ってアプリを動作させてデータを作成しておき、そのデータをアプリに組み込んでリリースします。

使用するときは、読み込み専用なら、アプリに組み込んだファイルを直接読み込めばいいです。
もし更新が発生するなら、初回起動時に組み込んだファイルを書き込み可能な場所（ドキュメントディレクトリなど）にコピーして使用します。

アプリケーションバンドル内のデータを直接読み込むには下記のようにします。
例のファイル名は「Places.realm」です。

```
let mainBundle = NSBundle.mainBundle()
let seedFilePath = mainBundle.pathForResource("Places", ofType: "realm")

let config = Realm.Configuration(readOnly: true, path: seedFilePath)

Realm.Configuration.defaultConfiguration = config

let realm = try! Realm()
```

更新が必要な場合は、このファイルをドキュメントディレクトリなどにコピーしてから利用します。

```
let mainBundle = NSBundle.mainBundle()
let seedFilePath = mainBundle.pathForResource("Places", ofType: "realm")

let documentDir: NSString = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.DocumentDirectory, .UserDomainMask, true)[0]
let realmPath = documentDir.stringByAppendingPathComponent("Places.realm")

try! NSFileManager().copyItemAtPath(seedFilePath!, toPath: realmPath)

let config = Realm.Configuration(readOnly: true, path: realmPath)

let realm = try! Realm()
```

（tvOSですが）下記のサンプルコードが役に立つかと思います。組み込み済みのデータをアプリで表示するサンプルです。

https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa/tree/master/examples/tvos/swift/PreloadedData

もし、分からないことがある場合は、Realmにはチャットのサポート http://slack.realm.io/ やFacebookのユーザーグループ https://www.facebook.com/groups/realmjp/ がありますのでそちらで聞かれるのも良いと思います。より適切にアドバイスできると思います。

Comment: 非常にわかりやすい解説ありがとうございました。
問題が解決しました。
また何かありましたら、チャットサポート等使わせて頂きます。